# How to set logo for an repository/image on docker hub

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I'm publishing our product image to the docker hub. We created the docker hub account, organization and push our docker image to a repository. Now we specified the avatar to the docker hub account successfully. It works.

I cannot specify a logo to my docker image/repository. I see many docker images have dedicated logo. But I didn't find any place to specify the logo.

I search for the solution on the internet. But I still didn't find it. I'm not sure if we have to join the DTP(Docker Technology Partner) or put the logo file in dockerfile or other places that docker hub can get it.

Answer (score 10):

I'm fairly sure this is not possible currently without becoming a Verified Publisher through the Docker Technology Partner Program.

You can see at the documentation link below that when you publish through the program you can submit a "product icon/logo."

https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/publish/publish/#prepare-your-image-manifest-materials

Further, the Docker Hub API does not seem to expose any way to set a logo. You can see the fields exposed for the repository resource at the link below. (Can't find official documentation for this API, by the way)

https://github.com/RyanTheAllmighty/Docker-Hub-API#repositoryusername-name